# Writing an element of a free product of $C_2$'s as a product of order-$2$ elements

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups

My question is simple: Suppose that $G$ is isomorphic to the free product of finitely many copies of $C_2$.  Is it true that any element $g \in G$ can be written as a product $g = s_1 \dotsm s_m$ such that each $s_i$ has order $2$ and such that for $i \neq j$ the terms $s_i$ and $s_j$ are in distinct conjugacy classes of the subgroup $\langle s_1, \dotsc , s_m \rangle \subseteq G$?

This seems like a very simple and elementary question, but I've spent too many hours already trying to solve it (I think the answer is positive) and imagine that someone better versed in geometric group theory might know of a place in the literature where results of this type have been proved.

Update: several people have said this should be true but flaws were found in their arguments. Meanwhile, I believe I've managed to reduce it to the following case: the element $g \in G$ can be written as a product of order-$2$ elements $t_1 \cdots t_n$ such that

- each $t_i$ appears an odd number of times in the product;
- if $t_i$ and $t_j$ are conjugate in $G$, then $t_i = t_j$; and
- for each $i \neq j$, the product obtained by deleting all terms $t_k$ for $k \neq i, j$ in the product $t_1 \cdots t_n$, after simplifying by cancelling out adjacent pairs of $t_i$'s and adjacent pairs of $t_j$'s, is either $t_i t_j$ or $t_j t_i$.

For this special case, I conjecture something stronger than the original claim: $g$ can be written as a product $s_1 \cdots s_m$ with $s_i^2 = 1$ and such that the following holds: there are $m$ elements in the underlying set of the multiset $\{t_1, \dots , t_n\}$ which can be written $t'_1, \dots, t'_m$ such that each $s_i$ is conjugate to $t'_i$ in $\langle t'_1, \dots, t'_m \rangle$.

EDIT: The stronger statement conjectured just above appears to be false; I think (just as the bounty period is ending) that I have found a counterexample in the element $cababcabcbabababa$ of the group $G := \langle a, b, c \ | \ a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = 1 \rangle$.  The stronger statement would imply that this could be written as the product of palindromes with *distinct* center letters (one with $a$, one with $b$, and one with $c$), and it doesn't seem possible to do this.  This still does not provide a counterexample to the original question, though, since I can write
$$cababcabcbabababa = (cabac)(cbc)(abcba)(bab)(aba),$$
and as far as I can tell, the elements $cabac, cbc, abcba, bab, aba$ are pairwise non-conjugate within the subgroup they generate.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Take $G=C_2*C_2=\langle s\mid s^2\rangle*\langle t\mid t^2\rangle$. Every element of order 2 is of the form $s^a$ or $t^b$ for some $a,b\in G$, so a decomposition of the form you ask for must be one of $s^a$, $t^b$, $s^at^b$ or $t^bs^a$ (if the element is non-trivial). But all of these are non-trivial in the abelianisation of $G$, so the element $stst$ can't be written in this form.

Comment: No, they only have to be non-conjugate *within the subgroup they generate* (otherwise, you would be right that this is too much to ask). So we can write $stst = t^s t$, and $t^s$ and $t$ are non-conjugate in the subgroup $\langle t^s, t \rangle$, even though they are conjugate in $G$.

Comment: Ah right — I thought I must have missed something.

Comment: Presumably you have an application for this rather delicate conjecture. Can I suggest you share the application? Your groups G are very well understood, so there’s likely to be another route.

Comment: @HJRW the application is a little involved, but the gist is that I'm looking at subgroups $G < \mathrm{PGL}_2(K)$ where $K$ is a $p$-adic field and $G$ is isomorphic to a free product of $C_2$'s. Letting $G_0 \lhd G$ be the subgroup of even-lettered words, I want to show that $G_0$ contains a nontrivial non-loxodromic element if and only if there are distinct order-2 elements of $G$ whose pointwise-fixed paths in the Berkovich projective line intersect nontrivially. I have an intricate argument for this which, in the very last line, uses a positive answer to my above question as a lemma.

Comment: I see. I take it the "even lettered words" means the commutator subgroup $G'$? I'm no expert on the Berkovich projective line, but my memory is that it's an $\mathbb{R}$-tree. So I think your question becomes: whenever $G$ acts on an $\mathbb{R}$-tree and some point has infinite stabiliser, must two distinct order-two elements have a common fixed point? (The other direction is obvious.) I think the answer is yes, and can imagine how a proof might go, but perhaps it would make sense as a separate MO question? (Or you could just e-mail me.)